# Uso de Fechas en Python

Tags: python, date

Estoy realizando un programa que permita calcular los impuestos que debe pagar un auto, conociendo su modelo (año de fabricación) y tipo (P: Particular/T: Taxi/R: Remis). Para calcular los impuestos, tener en cuenta que:

a. Los autos particulares de menos de 10 años de antigüedad pagan $200, entre 10 y 20 años pagan $150 y no pagan impuestos los que tienen más de 20 años.

b. Los taxis pagan impuestos como auto particular, más $150 por la licencia de taxi.

c. Los remises pagan $100 por cada año de antigüedad de su vehículo.

Para esto necesito obtener la antigüedad del vehículo aparir de su año de fabricación

¿cual es la manera de manejar fechas en python?

Comment: brother, bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo que revises: http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas cómo funciona el sitio. Con todo el respeto del mundo, aquí las preguntas del tipo "Haz mi tarea", se quedan en visto o son cerradas o usuarios como quien te escribe se toma el tiempo de enseñarte y guiarte. Si recién has empezado, intenta, crea, desarrolla y si te quedas a medio camino, con todo el gusto del mundo te ayudamos a completar el camino. Aquí te dejo unos enlaces: http://pythonya.appspot.com/ y https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm éxitos con el desarrollo de software :D

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ¡Recien estoy empezando en esto de programacion y trato de ponerle la mejor

Comment: de nada hermano, estamos para servir :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import date

antique=date.today().year-modelo

    if antique> 20:
       impuesto=0
    elif antique>10:
       impuestos=150
    elif:
       impuestos=200

    if tipo=='t':
     impuestos+=150
    elif tipo=='r':
     impuestos=antique*100
```

Comment: Hola Jorge, por favor, asegúrate de seguir las recomendaciones de [__esta guía__](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) al contestar, especialmente las secciones _"Contesta la pregunta"_ y _"Contesta preguntas bien formadas"_. Gracias.